# Sentinel HASP Hardlock - Where is the Secure Storage Located on disk

Tags: software-security, dongle

I have a provisional license for a program attached to a specific computer. The license according to hasp resides in the "secure storage of your pc" does anyone know where this is? If I reset the pc the license is not detected which makes me think the HASP Hardlock is located in the Windows directory. If I could wipe the  hardlock I could add a new provisional license and repeat this for an infinite 30 day trial.

Answer (score 1):

For my knowledge , HASP has a USB pen with something inside and two different drivers running as a service to accept remote and local request of license verification... And the other one is something I do not recall .

Probably you could sniff protocol (port 1943 for example) .

Sorry but I had not access to the phisical USB pen

Probably you can also clone it and mount on a virtual machine, but I hadn't tried.

Comment: I can install a provisional license without any dongle, it stores the license somewhere on disk just trying to find out where. I know it communicates through a driver with on disk secure storage, I just want to know how to wipe this.

Comment: Another idea is using thinapp. It is very elaborated . You must setup a clean environment, on a VM, launch thin app, launch setup, stop thin app. When you later launch the newly created setup for portable, it creates file on a subdirectory , and do not touches nothing on the machine. You can also see generated file after first run to understand what it creates.